# "Set<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>>" really?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have been using a little generic method to create sets from vararg of elements, eg

```
public <T> Set<T> createSet( T... elements ) { ...
```

Recently, however, I came across a situation where the compiler did not do what I expected it to do. Of the following createSet() uses only s3 works.

```
Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> s1 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class );

Set<? extends Class<Throwable>> s2 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class );

Set<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>> s3 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class );
```

Can anyone give a clear explanation of why s3 works and what might be wrong with my thinking regards s1 -- which was my initial coding? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is simply with the inference logic.  `s1` works just fine (well, except for vararg warnings) if you **explicitly** type the method call:

```
Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> s1 = 
    this.<Class<? extends Throwable>>createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class );
```

But by default the return type given your parameters is a `Set<Class<? extends Exception>>` (I suppose because it's the most specific possibility).  You just need to give the compiler a hint here, since without it, it is essentially trying to do this:

```
Set<Class<? extends Exception>> temp = createSet(Exception.class, RuntimeException.class);
Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> s1 = temp;
```

Which is not allowed since from the compiler's point of view, you could then put a `OutOfMemoryError.class` into `temp` which would violate its type.

### Edit

The reason `s3` works for you is because a `Class<? extends Exception>` is assignable to `Class<? extends Throwable>`:

```
//this works
Class<? extends Exception> exceptionRef = Exception.class;
Class<? extends Throwable> throwableRef = exceptionRef;
```

and so the `extends` keyword affords you the ability to convert from a `Set<Class<? extends Exception>>` to a `Set<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>>`:

```
//this works too
Set<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptionSetRef = ...;
Set<? extends Class<? extends Throwable>> throwableSetRef = exceptionSetRef;
```

Unfortunately, that's probably not what you want since now you can't put anything into `throwableSetRef`.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because closest common type of Exception and RuntimeException is an Exception, not a Throwable. T in invokation of createSet() is inferred to be `Class<? extends Exception>`, and it's illegal to assign `Set<Class<? extends Exception>>` to a variable of type `Set<Class<? extends Throwable>`

This works:

```
Set<Class<? extends Exception>> s1 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class );
```

Comment: But if he adds `OutOfMemoryError.class` it won't work anymore, because it doesn't go through the `Exception` hierarchy.

Comment: yes, but then the original s1, `Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> s1 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class, OutOfMemoryError.class);`, works.

Comment: But if he uses both `createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class);` and `createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class, OutOfMemoryError.class);` in his code, you are doomed.

Comment: Why? `Set<Class<? extends Exception>> s3 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class); Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> s1 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class, OutOfMemoryError.class);` compiles fine.

Comment: But it is inconvenient for using. You have to calculate the right type.

Comment: +1, you beat me to the meat of the explanation.  But being forced to change the variable type (potentially to an unwanted alternative) is probably not as elegant as instructing the compiler to use the type you want.

Answer (score 1):

To make possible problems of `s1` and `s2` more clear, let's replace `Class<T>` with `List<T>`.

Then:

```
List<RuntimeException> runtimeExceptions = new ArrayList<RuntimeException>();

Set<List<RuntimeException>> listsOfRuntimeExceptions =
    new HashSet<Lis<RuntimeException>>();
listsOfRuntimeExceptions.add(runtimeExceptions);

Set<? extends List<? extends Throwable>> listsOfThrowables = 
    listsOfRuntimeExceptions; // This is legal 

Set<List<? extends Throwable>> s1 = listsOfThrowables; // Imagine that this is legal
s1.add(Arrays.asList(new Exception())); // Type safety of listsOfRuntimeExceptions is violated

Set<? extends List<Throwable>> s2 = listsOfThrowables; // Imagine that this is legal
s2.get(0).add(new Exception()); // Type safety of runtimeExceptions is violated
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here comes from how the compiler determines the "upper bound" (in terms of Types) for the varargs you have. If we check http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/non-reifiable-varargs-type.html, we can see that for `s1`, the upper bound that you get is `Class<? extends Exception>` (and a warning telling that is generated). The error then is because at the end you try to convert `Set<Class<? extends Exception>>` to `Set<Class<? extends Throwable>>`. If you rewrite s1 to:

```
Set<Class<? extends Throwable>> s1 = createSet( Exception.class, RuntimeException.class, Throwable.class);
```

then the upper bound type is `Set<Class<? extends Throwable>>`, generating again a warning but no error.